# Pandas 'Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported' on train_test_split returned data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

For some reason train_test_split, despite lengths being identical and indexes look the same, triggers this error.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

data = {'col1':[30.5,45,1,99,6,5,4,2,5,7,7,3], 'col2':[99.5, 98, 95, 90,1,5,6,7,4,4,3,3],'col3':[23, 23.6, 3, 90,1,9,60,9,7,2,2,1]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.10)
X = train[['col1', 'col2']]
y2 = train['col3']

X = np.array(X)

kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index]
```

y is a pandas Series (same length as x).
x was a dataframe with about 20 numerical columns casted to numpy array.

For some reason train_test_split triggers the error despite the lengths being identical.

If i dont call train_test_split it works fine.

the last line triggering the error due to trying to index numpy array this way:
y[train_ind]

Comment: Your question includes missing parameters such as what is r? y? folds? Please see minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Can you try `xtrain,ytrain = x[train_ind],y[train_ind]`

Comment: That produces the same error and x[train_ind:],y[train_ind] gives: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Tell us about `x` - shape, dtype?  Also `train_ind`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've tried to create a scenario for your situation.

I've created following dataframe:

```
    col1  col2  col3
0      1     2     1
1      3     4     0
2      5     6     1
3      7     8     0
4      9    10     1
5     11    12     0
6     13    14     1
7     15    16     0
8     17    18     1
9     19    20     0
10    21    22     1
11    23    24     0
12    25    26     1
13    27    28     0
14    29    30     1
```

I set `col1` and `col2` for X and `col3` for y. After this I've converted X to numpy array as following. Only difference is I've used `shuffle` in `KFold`.

```
X = df[['col1', 'col2']]
y = df['col3']
X = np.array(X)
kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, y_train = X[train_index], y[train_index]
```

And it worked well. So please check my code and your code and clarify it if there is something I missed.

### Update

I assume y2 is y. So y type is still `Series`, you need to use `.iloc` for it. Following code worked well.

```
data = {'col1':[30.5,45,1,99,6,5,4,2,5,7,7,3], 'col2':[99.5, 98, 95, 90,1,5,6,7,4,4,3,3],'col3':[23, 23.6, 3, 90,1,9,60,9,7,2,2,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.10)

X = train[['col1', 'col2']]
y = train['col3']

X = np.array(X)

kf = KFold(n_splits=3, shuffle=True)
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
    X_train, y_train = X[train_index], y.iloc[train_index]
```

Comment: You are right. It has something to do with  train_test_split function in sci kit. For some reason the data types returned look exactly the same , but produces error. Ill update the question.

Answer (score 3):

if that helps anyone, I was having the same problem using .groupby function on a dataframe. I fixed it by using:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```